# algorithm2e: how to add space after SetKwInOut?

Tags: spacing, algorithm2e, microtype

With `algorithm2e`, if you use `\SetKwInOut`, it will put the argument right after the colon.

[image: no space after 'Data' and 'Result']

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \SetKwInOut{Data}{Data}
    \SetKwInOut{Result}{Result}
    \Data{my data}
    \Result{my result}
    \caption{My algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to add an additional space before *my data* and *my result*.

How could I do?

**EDIT**

It appears the problem is not caused by `algorithm2e`, which I have up to date, but by `microtype`, which I didn't suspect about at first and therefore didn't add to my MWE.

If you use `microtype`, the solution is to disable protusion for algorithms:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}

\begin{document}

{\microtypesetup{protusion=false}
\begin{algorithm}[ht]
    \SetKwInOut{Data}{Data}
    \SetKwInOut{Result}{Result}
    \Data{my data}
    \Result{my result}
    \caption{My algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\microtypesetup{protusion=true}}

\end{document}
```

I'll upvote both replies and mark as answer Werner's one because it shows how to customize `\SetKwInOut`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest would be to add the space yourself using `\Data{~my data}` and `\Result{~my result}` (here `~` inserts a non-breaking inter-word space).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \SetKwInOut{Data}{Data}
  \SetKwInOut{Result}{Result}
  \Data{~my data}
  \Result{~my result}
  \caption{My algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that the insertion of `~` is in addition to an existing `~` within the definition of each macro defined by `\SetKwInOut` (see below).

---

If you wish to make these adjustments to `\SetKwInOut` in the preamble, here's the original definition:

```
\newcommand{\SetKwInOut}[2]{%
  \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo:}}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname InOutSizeDefined\endcsname\relax% if first time used
    \newcommand\InOutSizeDefined{}\setlength{\inoutsize}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo\hfill:}}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
  \else% else keep the larger dimension
    \ifdim\wd\algocf@inoutbox>\inoutsize%
    \setlength{\inoutsize}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo\hfill:}}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \fi%
  \fi% the dimension of the box is now defined.
  \algocf@newcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@hanginginout}}{\relax}{\algocf@seteveryparhanging{\relax}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@inoutnumbered}}{\relax}{\algocf@seteveryparnl{\relax}}%
    {\let\\\algocf@newinout\hangindent=\inoutindent\hangafter=1\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo\hfill:}}~##1\par}% <--------
    \algocf@linesnumbered% reset the numbering of the lines
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@hanginginout}}{\relax}{\algocf@reseteveryparhanging}%
  }}%
```

The line highlighted with the arrow points to the location where the function is created. It inserts `~` before the argument already. However, you can copy-and-paste the above definition, change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand`, wrap it within a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair and change the spacing to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your version of `algorithm2e.sty`. The [current version on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty), release 5.1 from 19 Oct 2015, produces the following output, which contains an additional space.

[image]