# How to remove extra space in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, acm, acmart, sigplanconf

I am using `algorithm2e` package to write an algorithm. I need to define functions where their descriptions are multi-lines. In the first function only, `algorithm2e` adds extra space in the second, third, ..etc. line. But from the second function and afterwards, it does not add this extra space which looks as I want. I need to remove the extra space added in the first function lines (all lines after the first line). The script is here. I use ACM conference template and I need the algorithm in 2 columns as it is long (not like this small sample).

Here is the script:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{multicol} 

\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithm*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}\SetKwInOut{Functions}{Functions}
    \SetKwFunction{Query}{Query}\SetKwFunction{Calc}{Calc}


    \Functions
    {
        \Query{$a,b$}: Queries a and b and returns the answer as c. This function name is Query.\;
        \Calc{$a,b$}: Calculates a and b and returns the answer as c. This function name is Calc.\;
    }


\caption{The algorithm}
\label{alg:query-verify}
\end{multicols}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the figure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335862/90297:

Basically renew the \SetKWInOut command so that the indent size would be 0em.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{multicol} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\SetKwInOut}[2]{%
  \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo:}}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname InOutSizeDefined\endcsname\relax% if first time used
    \newcommand\InOutSizeDefined{}\setlength{\inoutsize}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo\hfill:}}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{0em}%{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}% <------------
  \else% else keep the larger dimension
    \ifdim\wd\algocf@inoutbox>\inoutsize%
    \setlength{\inoutsize}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo\hfill:}}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{0em}%{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}% <------------------
    \fi%
  \fi% the dimension of the box is now defined.
  \algocf@newcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@hanginginout}}{\relax}{\algocf@seteveryparhanging{\relax}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@inoutnumbered}}{\relax}{\algocf@seteveryparnl{\relax}}%
    {\let\\\algocf@newinout\hangindent=\inoutindent\hangafter=1\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2\algocf@typo\hfill:}}~##1\par}
    \algocf@linesnumbered% reset the numbering of the lines
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@hanginginout}}{\relax}{\algocf@reseteveryparhanging}%
  }}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{Algorithm}
\begin{algorithm*}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{output}\SetKwInOut{Functions}{Functions}
    \SetKwFunction{Query}{Query}\SetKwFunction{Calc}{Calc}



    \Functions
    {
        \Query{$a,b$}: Queries a and b and returns the answer as c. This function name is Query.\;
        \Calc{$a,b$}: Calculates a and b and returns the answer as c. This function name is Calc.\;
    }



\caption{The algorithm}
\label{alg:query-verify}
\end{multicols}
\end{algorithm*}

\end{document}
```